# Supertest / Jest / Node - Cannot test a simple route

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, supertest

I have been trying to test this route for 4 hours now, and I can't seem to make it work.

So i have a route like this:

```
api.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    let hasErrors = false
    if(!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.password){
        hasErrors = true
    }
    if(hasErrors){
        res.status(errCode.invalid_input).json({
            message: 'Invalid input'
        })
    }else{
    const NewUser = new User({
        _id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    });
        NewUser.save().then(saved_user => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'User registered',
        user: saved_user
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: err
      });
    })
  }
})
```

...which I'm testing using Jest and Supertest:

```
it('/register should return 201 if valid input', (done) => {
    //mock valid user input
    const NewUser = {
        'name': 'John Wick',
        'email': 'john@wick.com',
        'password': 'secret'
    }
    request(app)
        .post('/register')
        .type('form')
        .send(NewUser)
        .expect(201)
        .end((err) => {
            if (err) return done(err)
            done()
        })
})
```

And the test is pending, and It gives me `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.`

I have tested this /register endpoint manually with Postman, and indeed, when I call the /register endpoint with **Form URL Encoded** data (name, email, password), it works and adds a new entry in my database. If I send the data as **Multipart Form**, it doesn't work and gives a 422 Invalid Input. Maybe that's the cause of my problem?

Cheers!